# Define action of the Angular SnackBar Globally

Tags: angular, typescript, snackbar

I would like to know is it possible to set up action of the Angular SnackBar globally?
I have read trough the other questions on stackoverflow and on official Angular documentation. I only found setup for the duration. I have tried to define global variable in  MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS under key aciton but this didn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

app.module

```
 providers: [
    {provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {duration: 3000,  panelClass: 'block-snackbar'}},
  ]
```

component.ts

```
this.snackBar.open(this.translate.instant('my-text'), 'Close')
```

I would ideally love to have something like this but it's not working :

```
//app.module.ts

 providers: [
    {provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {duration: 3000,  panelClass: 'block-snackbar', actions: 'Close'}},
  ]

//component.ts

this.snackBar.open(this.translate.instant('common_snack_article_create')) // notice no second parameter of string that defines the action.
```

Comment: Message and Action button text is directly set by `open` method's parameters `_config.data = {message, action};` So there is no other way to set text only snackBar content.

Comment: Thanks do you want to edit your comment as answer and I will accept it.